# mef and windowsAPICodepack

Tags: .net, wpf, mef

Hi stackoverflow fellas,

I've got a problem which at first looks solved but I can't get it to run.

I've got one WPF application project in my solution and a WPF class library which is added at runtime via MEF. In this external Dll I use the TaskDialog of the Codepack.

Ok I found the manifest dependency thing and added it to my main WPF app.manifest. And also I wrapped my TaskDialog calls in my external Dll into a using which contains the well known EnableThemingInScope class.

Despite all those things my app stops through debugging when calling the Show method on the TaskDialog with the EntryPointNotFoundException.

So how do I get the dependency settings into the vshost.exe Since everything runs fine when not debugging?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to add the file "<appName>.vshost.exe.manifest" to the directory, but I believe this should be generated for you